# Is there a way to retrieve the module name from the controller?

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to retrieve the module name from the controller? Like `Application` in default case.

Comment: what do you mean module? is it current class name? smth like  get_class($this) ?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you mean the module name? Based upon your reference to `Application` as a default value, it sounds like you might mean the appnamespace associated to any resource loaders. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module name is available from request object via the method `getModuleName()`. So, within a controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$moduleName = $request->getModuleName();
```